# UI bug when comment is not long enough

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface

I recently tried to ping a user about an edit I made to my post on their answer. However, as the "@" that I made in the comment was deleted, the comment was too short.

This caused the "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length" dialogue to show up, but it was cut off. The same occurs if you type a bunch of spaces before a short comment and try to post it.

Image:

[image]

If you then edit the comment to be long enough, as it's posted, more of the dialogue shows up, but still some of it is cut off. I do not have an image of this as it shows up on the screen for less than a second.

Will someone please fix this?

Comment: Yeah, minimum limits do not make much sense. Perhaps are intended to avoid "Thanks!" comments and to encourage to use the chat feature (which many of us don't really like).

Comment: @Acorn The point was the UI bug (where the dialogue box is cut off).

Comment: [Same problem, different UI element](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332845/332043)